# Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference in VBA

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference-value

In VBA, if I want to pass arguments `ByVal` and `ByRef` simultaneously. As far as I understand it the following code should work just fine (and so far my test confirms that):

```
Sub Test(ByVal Var1 As String, ByRef Var2 as String, Var3 as String, ByVal Var4 As String)

    'Var1 should be passed ByVal
    'Var2 should be passed ByRef
    'Var3 should be passed ByRef (through default behaviour)
    'Var4 should be passed ByVal

    End Sub
```

Or is there anything I have to consider?

Comment: That's about it.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, feel free to write a quick answer.